# Magento 2 $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder() and $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId() returning null

Tags: sales-order, payment-gateway, onestepcheckout, checkout-page, checkoutsession

```
$this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()
$this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId()
```

returning null after payment gateway redirect.

Strange thing is that it is working some time and after it stops working.

> What is the issue and how to get paid order on success page ?

Comment: I have same issue in Magento 2.3.6-p1

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Magento 2.4.2, disabled cache, varnish etc, issue still persists don't know what is wrong !! Magento Sucks !!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing the cache?

If it doesn't work, try following these steps:

1. Pass **Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface** and
   **Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool** to your file’s constructor
   as the following:

   ```
   public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
       $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
   }
   ```
2. Add these lines to the method where you want clear/ flush cache:

   ```
   $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
   foreach ($types as $type) {
       $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
   }
   foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
       $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
   ```